# xcode iOS compare strings

Tags: ios, xcode

How do i compare a website result with a predicted result.

```
@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].outerHTML"
```

is predicted to contain:

```
<body>OK</body>
```

But i always get an error saying that they don't match. I used this code below to compare them:

```
if (webresult == cmp){
```

then it shows an alert saying success. Or in else it'll say error. It always goes to else. Heres the code block, Please help.

```
- (IBAction)displayresult:(id)sender {
    webresult = [webview2 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].outerHTML"];
    NSString *cmp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<body>OK</body>"];

    if (webresult == cmp) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logged in" message:@"Logged in, Proceeding to the game" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [alert show];
       [alert release];
   } else {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:webresult delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
}
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I assume that `webresult` is an `NSString`. If that is the case, then you want to use:

```
if ([webresult isEqualToString:cmp]) {
```

instead of:

```
if (webresult == cmp) {
```

as the above method checks if the strings are equal character by character, whereas the bottom method checks if the two strings are the same pointer.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (webresult == cmp)
```

Here, `==` checks whether `webresult, cmp` are pointing to the same reference or not. You should instead compare value of the object by using [NSString::isEqualToString.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
 if ( [ cmp isEqualToString:webresult ]) {
   // ..
 }else {
   // ..
 }
```

Note that `isEqualToString` is a good option because it returns boolean value.

Comment: Can i get an example of how to use that?

Answer (score 4):

We cannot comapre the strings with  `==`
We have to use `isEqualToString:`

```
if([str1 isEqualToString:str2])
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When comparing strings you need to use *isEqualToString:*

```
if ([cmp isEqualToString:webresult]) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for Swift 4.0:

```
if str1==str2 {
    //both string are equal 
}

else {
    //do something expression not true 
}
```

for Objective-C:

```
if ([str1 isEqualToString:str2]) {
    //both string are equal 
}

else {
    //do something expression not true 
}
```