# Can't get if then statement to work?

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement, geocoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xcode iOS compare strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936129/xcode-ios-compare-strings)

Trying to get a UIImageview to show a different image based on the location (city) of the user, here is the code I got:

```
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
        placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
        //Display country and city
        country.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:placemark.country];
        city.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:placemark.locality];
        if (placemark.locality==@"Cupertino")
            banner.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cupertino.png"];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
    }
} ];
```

I can get the labels to display the country and city, but can't get the UIImageview to change based on the city, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `isEqualToString:` method to compare the string, like

```
if ([placemark.locality isEqualToString:@"Cupertino"])
        banner.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cupertino.png"];
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have allocated the image using [UIImage alloc] ..