# Comparing NSStrings seems not to work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I am having some very frustrating trouble on what I'm sure is a very simple problem, but I cannot seem to fix it.   I have an NSArray called final that outputs as follows:

```
final = (
".DS_Store",
"hey.txt"
)
```

I want the following for loop to return false for the first pass and true for the second.  As far as I can tell I have it made correctly but the output is true for both passes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [final count]; i++) {
   if (final[i] != @".DS_Store") {
    NSLog(@"true");
   }
   else {
    NSLog(@"false");
   }
```

Outputs:

```
2013-02-20 17:20:39.042 myAppName [40636:403] true
2013-02-20 17:20:39.042 myAppName [40636:403] true
```

I cannot figure out why the first one does not return false.  Any Ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936129/xcode-ios-compare-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing pointers. Use `[final[i] isEqualToString:@".DS_Store"]` to compare strings.

Comment: Yes! I knew it was a simple answer.  Is there an unequal one? Like isNotEqualtoString?

Comment: No there isn't. But that's just basic C/Objective-C. Actually it's basic programming in any language, so I'll let you figure that one out for yourself.